# Android 4.0.3 emulator has no su

Tags: android, android-emulator

Recently I downloaded new Android revision (17). Now I have android emulator with android 4.0.3. When I type **adb shell su** in console, it returns me **su not found**.
I did the same in previous version of emulator and it worked perfectly! What's happened?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, they removed the `su` binary. Considering that `su` is not part of the Android SDK, that is certainly within their right to remove.